# UITapGestureRecognizer not calling it's target-action method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

For some reason, my `UITapGestureRecognizer` is not calling it's method when I tap a UIButton. What's really weird is that I used breakpoints in Xcode to make sure that the `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` method is returning YES. The gesture should be calling it's method, but it isn't. I have `cancelsTouchesInView` set to YES, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]] && !editingTaskName)
        return NO;
    else if ([touch.view isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
        return NO;

    return YES; // handle the touch
}
```

Here's the code where I set up all my gesture recognizers. Maybe the others are interfering with my tap gesture.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(longPress:)];
[longPress setMinimumPressDuration: 0.3];
[longPress setDelaysTouchesBegan: YES];

[self setLongPressGesture: longPress];
[[self tableView] addGestureRecognizer: longPress];

UITapGestureRecognizer *backToTableView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(backTapRecognized:)];
[backToTableView setCancelsTouchesInView: YES];
[backToTableView setDelegate: self];
[backToTableView setEnabled: NO];

[self setBackTapGesture: backToTableView];
[[self tableView] addGestureRecognizer: backToTableView];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(hideShowEditing:)];
[tap setCancelsTouchesInView: YES];
[tap setDelegate: self];

[self setEditTap: tap];
[[self tableView] addGestureRecognizer: tap];
```

Answer (score 2):

A button has its own tappability, so there's a conflict between the button and the gesture recognizer. In iOS 6, button wins; the gesture recognizer is thus prevented from recognizing.

In iOS 6, there is a UIView `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` method. The UIButton returns NO (that's built-in), so that's the outcome of the conflict.

This takes even higher priority than your `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`.

Comment: So if I wanted to stop the UIButton from having priority, I would have to subclass UIButton and override the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` method.

Comment: It would be simpler to attach a tap gesture recognizer to the button itself. Then that tap gesture recognizer would win. However, this kind of kills the button's own tap; why not just use the button's built-in action message and let the button work the way it wants to?

Answer (score -2):

Try setting the numberOfTapsRequired property of your UITapGestureRecognizer. Something like this should suffice:

```
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
```

Max